# Is this prepositional phrase adjective or adverb?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, adverbial-phrases, adjective-phrases

Is this prepositional phrase "with same sex quickstep" an adjective describing "history" or adverb modifying "makes in the sentence below?

> Andrew Makes ‘Dancing With The Stars’ History With Same-Sex Quickstep

Comment: It's best not to assume headlines follow normal grammar rules (whether in an attempt to digram them or to use them as a study source), because [they don't.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headline#Headlinese) I would strongly suggest you stop asking questions based on headlines and titles, because **they are not representative of standard written English.**

Comment: That said, an adjective modifies a noun, and an adverb modifies almost anything else in a sentence. What do you think "with same-sex quickstep" modifies?

Comment: The phrase is headed by the preposition "with", so it can only be a preposition phrase. Its function is another matter -- here it's a complement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible translation from headlinese into full-sentence English:

- Andrew makes ‘Dancing With The Stars’ history with **a** same-sex quickstep.

The tricky thing here is that *make history* is an idiom meaning to do something notable for the first time in history. To *make ‘Dancing With The Stars’ history* means to do something that has never been done before on the TV show. *With a same-sex quickstep* is *how* Andrew is making history; it is an adverbial modifier of *makes*.